# OpenGL skips a vertex when doing gradient

Tags: c, opengl, glut

When I do this:

```
void drawTest()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0); // red
    glVertex2d(-200, 100); // top-left

    glColor3d(0, 1, 0); // green
    glVertex2d(-200, 0); // middle-left

    glColor3d(0, 0, 1); // blue
    glVertex2d(-200, -100); // bottom-left

    glColor3d(0, 0, 1); // blue
    glVertex2d(200, -100); // bottom-right

    glColor3d(0, 1, 0); // green
    glVertex2d(200, 0); // middle-right

    glColor3d(1, 0, 0); // red
    glVertex2d(200, 100); // top-right
    glEnd();
}
```

I get this:

[image]

But when I switch to `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);` in the third line, the result is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the `GL_FILL` option skips the `middle-left` vertex when doing the gradient, while the `GL_LINE` option does it correctly.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `GL_POLYGON`.

The `GL_POLYGON` primitive type will be converted into a series of triangles, but the way this triangulation happens will be entirely up to the implementation. In your case, the implementation is probably taking the first 3 vertices and making a triangle out of them. Well, since the first 3 vertices are colinear, and therefore form a triangle with no area, nothing gets rendered for them.

You need a very specific triangulation, so triangulate it yourself and render with `GL_TRIANGLES`. For example:

```
float positions[] =
{
    -200, 100,      // top-left
    -200, 0,        // middle-left
    -200, -100,     // bottom-left
    200, -100,      // bottom-right
    200, 0,         // middle-right
    200, 100,       // top-right
};

//In the same order as `positions`.
enum pos_indices { top_left, middle_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, middle_right, top_right };

void position(pos_indices index)
{
    int ix = index * 2;
    glVertex2f(positions[ix], positions[ix + 1]);
}

float colors[] =
{
    1, 0, 0,    // red
    0, 1, 0,    // green
    0, 0, 1,    // blue
};

//In the same order as `colors`
enum color_indices { red, green, blue };

void color(color_indices index)
{
    int ix = index * 3;
    glColor3f(colors[ix], colors[ix + 1], colors[ix + 2]);
}

void drawTest()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        color(red);
        position(top_left);
        color(green);
        position(middle_left);
        color(red);
        position(top_right);

        color(green);
        position(middle_left);
        color(green);
        position(middle_right);
        color(red);
        position(top_right);

        color(green);
        position(middle_left);
        color(blue);
        position(bottom_left);
        color(green);
        position(middle_right);

        color(blue);
        position(bottom_left);
        color(blue);
        position(bottom_right);
        color(green);
        position(middle_right);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```